# permanent public hosted SCM for not open source things

Tags: svn, hosting

I'm looking for a public subversion host, but I don't necessarily want to open-source all projects hosted there (e.g. my resume).  I've checked out the popular free ones like google code but they seem to require me to choose an OSI license.  I'm willing to pay a small fee, company reputation matters because I want them to be around for several years.  ideas?

Edit: must allow hassle-free public browsing!  e.g. I want to publicly link to my head resume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/) is what you're looking for.

Some others:

- [Codespaces](http://www.codespaces.com/shop)
- [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com/)
- [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/)

For a small fee, you get private repos.

There is a list and comparison [here](http://www.straw-dogs.co.uk/09/20/6-free-svn-project-hosting-services/) of some others.

Answer (score 1):

[Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/) for Subversion

or if you'd consider another SCM...

[Github](http://github.com/) for Git

[BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org/) for Mercurial

Answer (score 1):

There are several out there. The three that I hear mentioned around the most are:

1. [CVSDude](http://cvsdude.com/)
2. [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/)
3. [CodeSpaces](http://www.codespaces.com/)

These offer free and/or low fee accounts. They are geared towards private projects. They also offer bug trackers and ticket systems. There are many more smaller outfits, but these three are the ones I hear about the most.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [InDefero](http://www.indefero.net) for Git and Subversion with free public/private projects (only limited by the size). It is a clone of GoogleCode and you can get it as GPL together with a full SQL dump of your hosted repositories. No lockin.